# Qt physics scene multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface, physics

I have a QGraphicsScene with about 1000 QGraphicsItems, which are actually physics items. Each frame they advance, check for collisions, and resolve those collisions, among other things. I would really like to have the physics multithreaded.

It is my understanding that the QGraphics classes are not thread-safe. Meaning, they can only be called from the main thread. Does this force me to send the final item properties (x, y, rotation) each frame to the main thread using a signal/slot mechanism, and then use a main thread method to actually update the QGraphicsItems? Or is there an easier way to do this?

What follows is just a hypothesis: Could I use QtConcurrent to run a method on my list of QGraphicsItems? If I use a QMutex in my QGraphicsItem paint method and a QMutex in my physics method (that will change properties of my QGraphicsItem), would this guarantee that only one thread is reading/writing each QGraphicsItem at any one moment in time?

Comment: I've read something about using QueuedConnection when connecting the signals/slots.  I haven't tried it or even looked into the details, but I think it's worth further investigation.  Does anyone else out there have experience with this?

Comment: I used the Delphi port of Box2D and I am very satisfied with it. Why not give a try to it? Head to this [page](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/02/26/qt-box2d-is-easy/) if you are interested.

Comment: Box2D looks interesting, but I don't see anywhere that it is multithreaded.

Comment: QtConcurrent looks interesting. I already have a list of my QGraphicsItems, and the physics would be easy if I could use QtConcurrent to run a function on each item. My understanding is that if 2 threads try to access the same memory at the same time, this could lead to problems. For example, the QGraphicsItem is painted while it is being modified by QtConcurrent. So, is there any way to "pause" painting of the scene while QtConcurrent is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > If I use a QMutex in my QGraphicsItem paint method and a QMutex in my
   >   physics method (that will change properties of my QGraphicsItem),
   >   would this guarantee that only one thread is reading/writing each
   >   QGraphicsItem at any one moment in time?

   No, it wouldn't. `QGraphicsItem` used heavily while drawing, not only `paint` method called. Look, for example, [here](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/graphicsview/qgraphicsscene.cpp#line4882). Even if it could work, it would be ugly solution, because apparently, `QGraphicsItem` can be used not only for painting.
2. > Does this force me to send the final item properties (x, y, rotation)
   >   each frame to the main thread using a signal/slot mechanism, and then
   >   use a main thread method to actually update the QGraphicsItems? Or is
   >   there an easier way to do this?

   Yes, you have to move item changing process to main thread. You actually have some alternatives:

   - Use signals/slots mechanism, as you mentioned.
   - Use [meta-calls](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) with `QueuedConnection`
   - Send custom events.

   Don't forget, that you has [`BlockingQueuedConnection`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), if you want to wait for painting finished.

   Also, you can use all this stuff with `QtConcurent`.

*Actually, it is not so difficult to manage. It is much safer and easier, than ensuring thread safety manually.*

The bigger problem is that you probably may fail even when trying to *read* items (using only `const` memebers, for example) in worker thread.

<sub>As far, as `QGraphicsItem` is not thread safe, even reading is *not*. And my experience of multithread app development in Qt tells me, that if something bad can happen, it *will* happen.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question: If I created a class that inherits QGraphicsItem, and added some custom properties (color, velocity, etc.), could I modify those from another thread? Will I be fine as long as I ensure that only one thread is reading/writing to each property at any one time?

Comment: @Joel, if they do not use other inherited members, you can. But I'd better used aggregating rather inheritance in this case (_your_ includes `QGraphicsItem` as a memeber), because in this case those properties serve some separate goals, not actually _extend_ `QGraphicsItem`. I personally think, it will increase clarity.

Comment: I'm not sure how an aggregation would work in my case. Just so we are clear, I want my class to reimplement the paint method. I'm not sure how I would do this without inheriting QGraphicsItem.

Comment: @Joel, you can inherit from `QGraphicsItem` _and_ create some struct, that will be used with threads.